# Add marker on map click with React and Mapbox

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to add a marker when i click on a map. Currently i have this, which works but the problem is that marker is added on map before i click on map. I think this is because default value of useState is [0,0], but if i leave this empty i get error. So how to fix this to only add marker when user clicks on map and when user clicks on a new position on map the previous marker gets removed and new one is added on clicked position so there is only one marker on map at all times.

I am using this library https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/

Thanks!

```
const [lngLat, setlngLat] = useState([
    0 0,
  ]);
  function addMarker(event) {
    const coordinates = event.lngLat;
    setlngLat(coordinates);
    console.log(lngLat);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Dashboard</h2>
      <ReactMapGL
        mapboxApiAccessToken={ }
        {...viewport}
        onViewportChange={(viewport) => setViewport(viewport)}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
        onClick={addMarker}
      >
        <Marker latitude={lngLat[1]} longitude={lngLat[0]}>
          <div>TEST</div>
        </Marker>
      </ReactMapGL>
    </div>
  );
```